# sfdx version cannot be updated

Tags: salesforcedx

I am using sfdx on mac.

I have tried:

```
sfdx update
npm update --global sfdx-cli
npm install --global sfdx-cli
```

And even:

```
npm uninstall --global sfdx-cli
```

and install back. But the version still remains 7.8.1.

How should I fix this?

Comment: This will look like asking obvious questions but I think it is needed to cross-out some of these. What is the exact output of `sfdx version` and `sfdx plugins --core` ? Do you have the latest version of node or which version do you have `node -v`?